# The Wien Bridge Oscillator

Tags: frequency, wien-bridge

The question is that: How could you make a Wien bridge tune to different frequencies?

Since the frequency is depended on the value of the resistor and capacitor we should use a variable resistor and capacitor. But, I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: As mentioned in the detailed answers, you must tune two elements at the same time. However, there are alternatives which allow single-element tuning - but you need an additional opamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single frequency Wien Osc. you need 2 resistors (of the same value) and 2 caps (of the same value). To vary the frequency over a large range you require a dual gang pot for the resistors so that you can vary their values together. Then have say 4 frequency bands. Each band would be selected by switching in a pair of same value capacitors. 8 capacitors in all. This avoids the difficulty of trying to implement a dual gang capacitor.

Here's one I designed a while ago.

[image: Wien Oscillator]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the block diagram of the iconic HP 204C oscillator:

[image]

As you can see, it uses a ganged air variable capacitor as the primary tuning elements.

A pot is used to adjust the amplitude as controlled by the AGC (automatic gain control).

The complete schematic is in the [manual](http://bama.edebris.com/download/hp/204c/HP%20204C.pdf) which can be downloaded. It uses BJTs and JFETs exclusively (no ICs at all).

Incidentally, my 204D, made approximately 50 years ago, still works fine.

Answer (score 1):

decades ago, in university, I built a 100:1 tuning-range Wein using cadmium cells from Edmunton Scientific. In a pack of 10, I found at least 2 that tracked (as light varied from a 28 volt bulb) rather well. To handle mistracking, another cell + another bulb was used to adjust the nominal_3:1 feedback gain.